# modify xml generated by flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash

I am new to flash and actionscript.

I want to modify the xml file of flash once it generated.

You can see this tutorial
http://www.webwasp.co.uk/tutorials/A_IntAct-02-drag-drop/index.php
here when i change the position i want new xml file with update.

Any Help is greatly Appriciated.
Thanks,

Comment: There are numerous examples on the page and none of them reference XML.  Can you expand on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: What new xml file? with what update?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am working on drag and drop example. If i change the (x,y) postion of an  object then it should be update in xml file. i want to know how can it is chaanged in xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not having mostly any idea what exactly your asking for, I created an example with a square that can be dragged and dropped. When its dropped it writes xml to an xml file with the x and y co-ordinates of the dropped square:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.filesystem.*;
    import flash.utils.*;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _square:Square;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            _square = new Square();
            _square.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onSquareMouseDown);
            addChild(_square);

        }// end function

        private function onSquareMouseDown(e:Event):void
        {
            _square.startDrag();

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStageMouseUp);

        }// end function

        private function onStageMouseUp(e:Event):void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStageMouseUp);
            _square.stopDrag();

            var xml:XML = <dragAndDrop>
                              <x>{_square.x}</x>
                              <y>{_square.y}</y>
                          </dragAndDrop>;

            var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("xml/dragAndDrop.xml");
            var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
            fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
            fileStream.writeMultiByte(String(xml), "iso-8859-01");
            fileStream.close();

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

import flash.display.Sprite;

internal class Square extends Sprite
{
    public function Square()
    {
        graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        graphics.endFill();

    }// end function

}// end class
```

Comment: @Hardik Patel, FYI, this is an Air project with pure AS3. `FileStream` is only available in Air.

Answer (score 0):

The examples given in the website refers to mx 2004. You can see a more up to date [example here](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flashcs3/using_xml_as3_pg1.htm).