# How to Create a New XML File and Write to it in Flash with ActionScript 3?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I am writing a program and want to take store user inputs into a XML document.

Example

Try for XML File's Existence

Catch Create XML File

I also want the options to:
Write to that file
Read from that file with Array usage

Security is no issue. This is a local file with no needed security.

How would I do this using AS3. Any good tuts?

Thanks!

Comment: AIR applications can use the flash.filesystem.File class http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633661/modify-xml-generated-by-flash/6636754#6636754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done exactly what you're proposing, successfully, with an Adobe Air project. You can also use MDM Zinc, but that's a paid product.

I used `File.save()` to create an `.xml` file in local storage for retrieval later. However, it will open  dialog box every time, so a class that updates that file once you have it's filepath would be awesome.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save()

Hope that helps!

J